# Why this code print both "initialization1" and "initialization2",but only 1 doAction?

Tags: scala

```
trait Action {
  def doAction
}

trait TBeforeAfter extends Action {
  abstract override def doAction: Unit = {
    println("Initialization")
    super.doAction 
    println("Destoryed")
  }
}

trait TBeforeAfter2 extends Action {
  abstract override def doAction: Unit = {
    println("Initialization2")
    super.doAction 
    println("Destoryed2")
  }
}

class Work extends Action {
  override def doAction = println("doAction")
}

object TraitLearning extends App {
  val work = new Work with TBeforeAfter with TBeforeAfter2
  work.doAction
}
```

Result output:

```
Initialization2
Initialization
doAction
Destoryed
Destoryed2
```

Could anybody tell me why trait be called twice while doAction only once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both traits, `Work` and their `doAction` methods are being called. This is how the call chain executes:

1. `work.doAction` -> This invokes `TBeforeAfter2.doAction`, as it is the last mixin in your instanstiation graph
2. `TBeforeAfter2.doAction` prints *"Initialization2"*, and invoked `super.doAction`, which is `TBeforeAfter.doAction`, the next mixin in your object graph
3. `TBeforeAfter.doAction` prints *"Initialization"*, and invokes it's `super`, which is `Work`.
4. `Work.doAction` prints *"doAction"*, and returns
5. `TBeforeAfter.doAction` prints *"Destoryed"* and returns to `TBeforeAfter2`
6. `TBeforeAfter2.doAction` prints *"Destroyed2"* and returns, and ends the call-chain.

Comment: Why statement2 said that TBeforeAfter2.doAction invoked "super.doAction", is TBeforeAfter.doAction rather than work.doAction?

Comment: Because TBeforeAfter2's super is TBeforeAfter: `Work with TBeforeAfter with TBeforeAfter2`